# DNS to direct url with path to another domain

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I run a website hosted by Bigcommerce at https://www.example.com.

I also have a Wordpress blog at http://blog.example.com.

I would like my blog to be accessible from https://www.example.com/blog. Is this possible to do with a CNAME or some other DNS entry?

Please keep in mind the website uses Bigcommerce nameservers. I don't have access to .htaccess or any server configuration besides DNS entries for A, CNAME, and TXT records.

Also, please note I do not want to redirect the user. I want /blog to load it's content from blog.example.com, but the user's browser should remain at example.com/blog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be done with DNS. This must be done with URL rewrites in your HTTP server. If you don't have access to any configuration settings for your web server, you're out of luck.

Comment: Bigcommerce does provide the ability to add 301 redirects, but I don't think this would help me since that will result in the user actually being redirected.

Comment: @flyingL123 Correct. You need rewrites, not redirects, to meet your stated requirements.

Comment: To me, rewrite and redirect are both wrong terms. To me, the correct term is reverse proxying. That is, the web server at `www.example.com` will fetch the content for `/blog` URI from `blog.example.com` server.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen That's yet another way to do it, yes. Rewriting or reverse proxying could achieve the same result from an end user perspective.

Comment: True, though rewriting requires that the services are hosted on the same nginx server, and that isn't clear from the question, and I assumed you meant proxying when using term rewrite, which is quite common here :)

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Cool. But if where you are they confuse proxying with rewriting, the terms are being used incorrectly both grammatically and historically.